# Why is my arrow pointing from one node to another not getting bent as I expect it to

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to write an arrow to point to an angle to specify its size.  But when I compile this, I just get a straight arrow.  (See last `\draw` statement for the problematic line of code.)

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{$#1^\circ$}
\begin{document}

\def\aes{in*0.54}%%
\def\aeang{70}%%
\def\aerise{2.15}%%
\def\aerun{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[scale=2]}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(3\aes,0)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(-90:2\aes)$);
  \coordinate (ttD) at ($(C)+(180:1\aes)$);

  \coordinate (tD) at ($(A)+(-63:1\aes)$);
  \tkzInterLL(A,tD)(C,ttD)
  \tkzGetPoint{D}

  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
  \draw (B) -- (D);

  \draw[arrows=->] (A) -- ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \draw[arrows=->] (D) -- ($(D)!0.5!(C)$);

  \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,C,D)

  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.5,anchor=east,xshift=3pt](A,B,D){$4x$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.65](B,D,A){\degrees{65}}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8](C,D,B){\degrees{52}}

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](D,B,C)
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \tkzGetPoint{tE}
  \coordinate (E) at ($(B)!8pt!(tE)$);

  \coordinate (lE) at ($(E)+(-40:0.5\aes)$);

  \node[anchor=west] (nlE) at (lE) {$(3y+5)$};
  \draw[arrows=-{>[scale=0.85]},out=180,in=-90] (nlE.west) -- (E);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\draw[arrows=-{>[scale=0.85]}] (nlE.west) [out=180,in=-90] to (E);` `--` always goes straight.

Comment: That's not exactly minimal, is it? More like putting the maximal into minimal....

Comment: @cfr Sorry about the "not exactly minimal".  I thought by mentioning the troublesome line I might be forgiven the other excesses.   :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--` always goes straight. You need something else for a curve. I think what you are looking for is a curved `to` path:

```
  \draw[arrows=-{>[scale=0.85]}] (nlE.west) [out=180,in=-90] to (E);
```

[image: curve]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{$#1^\circ$}
\begin{document}

\def\aes{in*0.54}%%
\def\aeang{70}%%
\def\aerise{2.15}%%
\def\aerun{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[scale=2]}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(3\aes,0)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(-90:2\aes)$);
  \coordinate (ttD) at ($(C)+(180:1\aes)$);

  \coordinate (tD) at ($(A)+(-63:1\aes)$);
  \tkzInterLL(A,tD)(C,ttD)
  \tkzGetPoint{D}

  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
  \draw (B) -- (D);

  \draw[arrows=->] (A) -- ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \draw[arrows=->] (D) -- ($(D)!0.5!(C)$);

  \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,C,D)

  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.5,anchor=east,xshift=3pt](A,B,D){$4x$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.65](B,D,A){\degrees{65}}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8](C,D,B){\degrees{52}}

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](D,B,C)
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \tkzGetPoint{tE}
  \coordinate (E) at ($(B)!8pt!(tE)$);

  \coordinate (lE) at ($(E)+(-40:0.5\aes)$);

  \node[anchor=west] (nlE) at (lE) {$(3y+5)$};
  \draw[arrows=-{>[scale=0.85]}] (nlE.west) [out=180,in=-90] to (E);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I had thought that `--` and `to` were essentially aliases.  Also, it seems from how you've written this, that where I declare the `out=...,in=....` makes a difference.  Could you explain why it doesn't seem to take effect is simply declared within the optional arguments to `\draw`?

Comment: Well, the `out` refers to the angle leaving the previous position on the path and the `in` to the angle entering the next one. So you can say `\draw (<coord>) [out=<angle>,in=<angle>] to (<coord>) [out=<angle>,in=<angle>] to (<coord>) [out=<angle>,...` and so on. As I understand it, some things apply to whole paths and others to sub-paths. I think that is just how it is designed. Otherwise, you'd have to have the same angles for all points on the path and that would be inconvenient, after all, since often you want them to be different!

Comment: I never thought of it that way.  That makes good sense.  And now thinking about it a bit, that sounds like the way it should be done.  :-P